# Play Framework 2.0 - views.render throws exception

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to get the hello world app running from the [doc](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/helloworld/app/controllers/Application.java).

I get the following error:

```
render(java.lang.String) in views.html.index cannot be applied to (play.data.Form<controllers.Application.Hello>)
```

Pointing to the following code block:

```
  /**
   * Home page
  */
  public static Result index() {
     return ok(index.render(form(Hello.class)));
  }
```

Also Eclipse cannot resolve the .render method on the index object.

```
the method render(String) in the type index is not applicable for the arguments (Form<Application.Hello>)
```

I defined the following imports:

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.data.*;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.*;

import java.util.*;
import views.html.*;
```

Also the hello.scala.html and the index.scala.html are available in the folder app/views/

Any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each view in Play 2.0 is Scala function which contains arguments, most probably you have in the index.sacala.html String declared at the beginning:

```
@(message: String)
```

and it should be your form:

in controller:

```
final static Form<MyModel> myForm = form(MyModel.class);

public static Result blank() {
    return ok(formNew.render(myForm));
}
```

and in the view:

```
@(myForm: Form[MyModel])
```