# Play Framework unable to properly passing a list to view

Tags: templates, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I am new to Play 2 Framework.

I have the following code:

```
import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.data.*;
import static play.data.Form.*;

import models.*;
import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller{
    public static Result index(){
        return ok(
                views.html.index.render(Task.find.all())
        );
    }
}
```

I am basically trying to populate the content of Task, by passing it to my view ("index.html").

However i keep getting the following error on intelliJ

render cannot be applied to java.utils.List

Can anyone help me with this one? Thank you

**EDIT:**

I've tried the solution given here:

[Play Framework 2.2.1 - Compilation error: "method render in class index cannot be applied to given types;"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993442/play-framework-2-2-1-compilation-error-method-render-in-class-index-cannot-b)

with no luck.

**EDIT 2**
I've tried this:

```
<!-- Line below specify paramters required from controller -->

@main("Dashboard") {
    <header>
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Dashboard</h1>
            <h2>Tasks over all projects</h2>
        </hgroup>
    </header>
}
```

And this

```
@import models.Task
@(tasks: List[Task])

@main("Dashboard") {
    <header>
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Dashboard</h1>
            <h2>Tasks over all projects</h2>
        </hgroup>
    </header>
}
```

And this:

```
@import models.Task
@(tasks: List[models.Task])

@main("Dashboard") {
    <header>
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Dashboard</h1>
            <h2>Tasks over all projects</h2>
        </hgroup>
    </header>
```

Yet, it still gives me the same error
which is:

Not found: value Tasks, and if i trace it back to controller it throws error saying that render() cannot accept value type of List.

**EDIT 3:**

SO i modified my code as follows

my controlller

```
public static Result index(){

    List<User> users = User.find.all();

    return ok(
            views.html.index.render(users)
    );
}
```

and my views:

```
@(users: java.util.List) /* You could also use @(users: List) if you want */

@main("Dashboard") {
    <header>
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Dashboard</h1>
            <h2>Tasks over all projects</h2>
        </hgroup>
    </header>

    <section>
    </section>
}
```

This time i get the following (compilation) error:

```
trait List takes type parameters
```

Comment: Could you please provide the first line of your template?

Comment: @Carsten Hi, i've added the code to my Views.

Comment: Try `@(users: java.util.List[package.path.to.User])`

Comment: @Carsten yup that's exactly what i did. I have posted my working solution. I am yet to accept it as an answer.

Comment: Good job solving it on your own! In case you didn't know, [answering your own questions is acutally encouraged by SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so you should probably mark it as accepted. I think there's even a badge for that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Solved it...

Turned out that the process is not as quite straight forward as i expected.

This is what i did

My Controller:

```
/* Do not forget to import the necessary library */
public class Application extends Controller{
    public static Result index(){

        List<User> users = User.find.all();
        return ok(
                views.html.index.render(users)
        );
    }
}
```

My Views:

```
@(users: List[models.User])

@main("Dashboard") {
    <header>
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Dashboard</h1>
            <h2>Tasks over all projects</h2>
        </hgroup>
    </header>

    <section>
        @for(user <- users){
            <p>@user.name (@user.email)</p>
        }
    </section>
}
```