# Play Framework compilation error when passing List object from controller to view

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I have a function in a controller that returns a list of User model records - I am using the [PlayStartApp](http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/PlayStartApp) template:

```
public Result getAllUsers() {
    List<User> users = User.find.all();
    return ok(searchusers.render(form(Login.class, users)));
}
```

This function works correctly and returns a List object.

I also have a view (html page) set with this to pass the object to the view:

```
@(loginForm: Form[Application.Login], userList: java.util.List[User])
```

When I compile in activator on the command line, I receive this error message:

```
[PlayStartApp] $ compile
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source and 1 Java source to C:\WebDev\git\PlayAuthentic
ate\target\scala-2.10\classes...
[error] C:\WebDev\git\PlayAuthenticate\app\controllers\Application.java:209: met
hod render in class views.html.searchusers cannot be applied to given types;
[error]   required: play.data.Form<controllers.Application.Login>,java.util.List
<models.User>
[error]   found: play.data.Form<controllers.Application.Login>
[error]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
[error] searchusers.render
[error] C:\WebDev\git\PlayAuthenticate\app\controllers\Application.java:215: no
suitable method found for form(java.lang.Class<controllers.Application.Login>,ja
va.util.List<models.User>)
[error]     method play.data.Form.<T>form(java.lang.Class<T>,java.lang.Class<?>)
 is not applicable
[error]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
[error]         (argument mismatch; java.util.List<models.User> cannot be conver
ted to java.lang.Class<?>))
[error]     method play.data.Form.<T>form(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class<T>,ja
va.lang.Class<?>) is not applicable
[error]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
[error]         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
[error]     method play.data.Form.<T>form(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class<T>) i
s not applicable
[error]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
[error]         (argument mismatch; java.lang.Class<controllers.Application.Logi
n> cannot be converted to java.lang.String))
[error]     method play.data.Form.<T>form(java.lang.Class<T>) is not applicable
[error]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
[error]         (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
[error] form
[info] Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get
 full output
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) javac returned nonzero exit code
```

I reviewed this post, but I am still having the same issue:
[Play Framework 2.2.1 - Compilation error: "method render in class index cannot be applied to given types;"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993442/play-framework-2-2-1-compilation-error-method-render-in-class-index-cannot-b)

Any help would be great!

EDIT:
I removed the Login form.  Code is now:

```
public Result getAllUsers() {
    List<User> users = User.find.all();
    return ok(searchusers.render(users));
}
```

My view now has:

```
@(userList: List[User])


@main(null) {

<ul>
@for(user <- userList) {
  <li>@user.fullname</li>
} 
</ul>

}
```

I am receiving this when compiling:

```
[error] C:\WebDev\git\PlayAuthenticate\app\controllers\Application.java:209:  no
 instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that play.data.Form<T> conforms to java.util.List<models.User>
```

Comment: Looks like you are using the wrong view file

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
ok(searchusers.render(form(Login.class, users)))
```

to

```
ok(searchusers.render(form(Login.class), users))
```

For clarity sake

```
Form[Application.Login] loginForm = form(Login.class)

ok(searchusers.render(loginForm, users))
```

You have to pass form as first argument and users as second argument, but you are trying to pass Login.class and users to form which is wrong.

Comment: I corrected the parentheses issue, but I still receive this message: `[error] C:\WebDev\git\PlayAuthenticate\app\controllers\Application.java:209: met
hod render in class views.html.searchusers cannot be applied to given types;
[error]   required: play.data.Form<controllers.Application.Login>,java.util.List
<models.User>
[error]   found: play.data.Form<controllers.Application.Login>
[error]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
[error] searchusers.render`

Comment: @Dan ... again the same issue . use it like this `searchusers.render(form(Login.class), users)`

Comment: @Dan you are not passing required number of arguments to render

Comment: @Dan use this `Form[Application.Login] loginForm = form(Login.class)

ok(searchusers.render(loginForm, users))
`

Comment: my code is this: `return ok(searchusers.render(form(Login.class), users)); ` I have 2 parameters being passed from the controller to the view.  For "render" - how many parameters do I need to pass?  I thought that had to match both the controller and the view.

Comment: I updated my code to: `public Result getAllUsers() {
  List<User> users = User.find.all();
  Form<Application.Login> loginForm = form(Login.class);
  return ok(searchusers.render(loginForm, users));
 }` but still get the same error

Comment: @Dan try to do `sbt clean` and then do `sbt compile`

Comment: @Dan clean and build the project agaiin

Comment: I edited my original post, please take a look when you get the chance

Comment: @Dan what is the name of the view file

Comment: searchusers.scala.html

Comment: @Dan did you try to clean and compile the project

Comment: I cleaned, compiled, closed and re-opened the command prompt and Eclipse...  Cleaned and Refreshed in Eclipse, started activator, cleaned and compiled again, but still get the message...